# Using SqlDependency in ASP.NET webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, webforms, sqldependency

I have been trying to use `SqlDependency` in webforms, when I try to show an alert in the `Onchange` method of `SqlDependency` I get an error:

> System.Web.HttpException: 'Response is not available in this context.'

When I try to, for example, set a textbox's value, it doesn't do so. I have tried the following code in C# winforms and it works perfectly - am I missing something?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        SqlDependency.Start(link);
        SomeMethod();
}

void OnDependencyChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
{
        Response.Write("<script>alert('row updated/deleted/inserted')</script>");
        
        dependency.OnChange -= OnDependencyChange;

        SomeMethod();
}

void SomeMethod()
{
    string link = "My database connection";

    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(link);

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT [id],[name],[age] " + "FROM [dbo].[People]", connection);

    SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
    dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(OnDependencyChange);

    connection.Open();

    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
}
```

Comment: Explain your goal, not your solution. HTTP works with request-response. Your SqlDependency fires after the response has already been sent, and potentially even after the connection was closed. You _probably_ want to update the UI when something changes in the database, you generally use SignalR (websockets) for this.

Comment: @CodeCaster i want to be notified with an alert when a record is updated,deleted or inserted in the database, is that possible with sqldependency inside webforms? or im obliged to use SignalR?

Comment: Again: Web Forms is request/response based because it follows the HTTP protocol. Therefore there is no updating of the UI once the response has been sent to the client. Therefore you must use techniques such as AJAX or web sockets to accomplish what you seek - SignalR being a framework that can accomplish that, and can be hosted in the same application as Web Forms.